# C program using SDL2 will not compile with clang

Tags: c, clang, sdl-2

I am having an issue trying to compile my C program. I'm on macOS Catalina and using clang to compile.

When I try to `SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );` and compile clang tells me there is a linker command failure

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main-1defaf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I used brew to install SDL2 with `brew install SDL2`. So these are flags I have tried to have clang pass to the linker but neither one worked.

```
  > clang main.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2

  > clang main.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2 \
  -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/lib
```

Since they did not work I then tried to add the `-framework` flag. I followed the instructions I found [here](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/mac/index.php) to install the framework. However the website didn't mention how to use it with clang. [Clangs documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#linker-flags) did not mention if I needed to point to the framework file or directory so I tried a couple different ways but could not get any to work.

```
  > clang main.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2 \
  -framework SDL2

ld: framework not found SDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

  > clang main.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2 \
  -framework /Library/Framework/SDL2.framework

ld: framework not found /Library/Framework/SDL2.framework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

  > clang main.c -L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2 \
    -framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/SDL2

ld: framework not found /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/SDL2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have also tried to just use XCode to compile and it builds successfully however fails to run with the error below. I followed the instructions in the tutorial linked above.

```
2020-06-30 16:07:36.220432-0700 sdl_test[1867:31873] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-06-30 16:07:36.273590-0700 sdl_test[1867:32300] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
2020-06-30 16:07:36.274022-0700 sdl_test[1867:32300] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I have restarted the computer and cleaned the build and based on some google searches it seems like this was introduced in a recent version of XCode that needs to be resolved.

I would like to stick with clang and not sure what else I can try to get this to compile. I would like to get some direction on next steps.

This is the code I am trying to run.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `pkg-config` instead? `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` (or possibly libsdl2). https://stackoverflow.com/a/38902949/14660

Comment: You didn't link against any libraries. The `-L` switch specifies which directories will be searched for the library names that you give .

Comment: I've been dealing with same issue when trying to use Xcode. I've also seen many people here and other forums having the same issue. Does anyone know how to fix that (while still using Xcode)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `-lSDL2` to bring in the shared library, and if you're going to use `/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.12_1/include/SDL2` you should only `#include <SDL.h>`.

Consider using [`pkg-config`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pkg-config) to handle include and link flags.

```
clang main.c -o main `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2`
```

Comment: `pkg-config` output should probably go after `main.c`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't believe that's correct. `pkg-config` outputs compiler options and clang is documented as `clang [options] filename ...`. In reality most programs don't care where you put the options.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with `-lSDL2` and `pkg-config`. I'll stick with pkg-config, thanks for the suggestion.  

`#include <SDL.h>` did not, still needed the `SDL2/` first.

Comment: I can't find a good reference right now, but ``clang `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2` main.c -o main`` doesn't work for me, I still get undefined references. But ``clang main.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2` -o main`` does work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Weird. What's `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2` outputting? The `pkg-config` docs do put it at the end, so I'll go with that.

Comment: @Schwern It's the `-l` flags that must be after the objects and/or sources (unless you're using a fancy linker like LLD). Most other flags can be placed anywhere.